# Trying to login to website that has an iframe sign in section?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe

First time coming across iFrames and such. Have just learnt the basics of Python and have created a similar script to log into websites. However, with this particular website I can't get past the iframe? Wesbite: https://www.trademe.co.nz I have tried using ChatGPT and have had not luck as of yet.

I got up to the login page and tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#opening firefox and going to Google homepage. 
browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
browser.get('https://www.google.co.nz')

#going to trademe.co.nz's website. 
search_elem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#APjFqb') 
search_elem.click()
time.sleep(3) 

search_elem.send_keys('trademe.co.nz')
search_elem.submit() 
time.sleep(5) 

seek_elem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md')
seek_elem.click()

#congratulations, you have gained access to seeks homepage website.
#signing into trademe.co.nz website. 
searchx_elem = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tm-shell-main-nav__mtm-link')
searchx_elem.click()

##iframe = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'tm-graffiti-iframe')
##time.sleep(3)
##browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
##time.sleep(3)
##queryElement = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'Email')
##time.sleep(3)
##queryElement.send_keys('test@hotmail.com')

try:
    # Wait up to 10 seconds for the element to load
    email_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Email')))
    email_input.send_keys("your_email@example.com") 
except:
    print("Couldn't locate the element")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have covered with the comment sign is generally correct. Try to wait for the element's presence instead of immediate interaction with it.

When working with the iFrame element, you should do the following actions:

- Find the iframe (make sure you are not using some dynamic attribute to locate the frame)
- use 'driver.switch_to.frame' (browser.switch_to.frame in your case) to switch to the frame. You can pass either frame name, index or located element to the 'frame' method
- Start looking for the elements inside of the frame, do the required actions
- Switch back to the default content (step out of the iFrame) via 'driver.switch_to.default_content()' (browser.switch_to.default_content() in your case)

Unfortunately, the website provided by you is not reachable to me, but here is an example of how to work with the element inside of the iFrame on [the-internet.herokuapp](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe)

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

try:
    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe")

    # find iframe and switch to it
    iframe = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.tox-edit-area__iframe')))
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    # now we are looking for the element inside the iframe
    ptag = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > p')))

    # do something with the located element
    print(ptag.text)
    ptag.send_keys("Writing some text to the <p> inside of the iframe")

    # go back to the 'root', i.e. leave the iframe
    driver.switch_to.default_content()

    # try to access the element inside the iframe when you are not in the iframe
    # THIS LINE WILL FAIL (!) BECAUSE WE ARE NOT IN THE IFRAME ANYMORE
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body > p')))
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tired the code you have given and it works with lcosing the browser but still can't find the iframe I am looking for. I can get to it but then can't interact or find the place to send keys to.

Comment: @vee2gee, can you share the source code of the target page? Or at least a screenshot of it? Due to some reason https://www.trademe.co.nz is not reachable to me.

Comment: hope this link works: https://codefile.io/f/tYYibQkNWO

Comment: @vee2gee, the link works, but I don't see the iframe tag there. The only tag that is visible is 'tm-auth-service-login-iframe'. Does the website have the native 'iframe' tag below the 'tm-auth-service-login-iframe' on your website? Maybe you can also take a screenshot of the page's source code near the required iframe, after the page is fully loaded

Comment: I have the code here: https://codefile.io/f/MCUMSqhHSL that is for the alleged iframe. This is the iframe line: ''' <iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-same-origin" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" style="display: none;" id="tm-graffiti-iframe" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/tm-frend-graffiti/index.html?gtmId=GTM-WKVT4M4"></iframe> ''' There are multiple iframes linked and scattered in the code unfortunately.

Comment: @vee2gee, so your iframe has a 'display:none' style. Are you sure that this is your target frame? Basically, you shouldn't see it on the page, as it is hidden. Even if you switch to it with selenium, you won't be able to interact with frame elements in a 'classic' way because they are simply not visible. Can you please double-check if that iframe is the one you need? (by inspecting the elements from dev tools) Also, are you able to find this iframe via selenium find_element? Or does it give NoSuchElementException?

Comment: Hey @sashkins, I do get the NoSucjElementException and I am not 100% sure if that is the target frame but that is the only one I can manage to find. This is going to be a ask hahah, but you got a VPN? maybe that way you could proxy to the website and have a look?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is CSS SELECTOR but that doesn't work either: <input class="email-input form-control" type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus="" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="Email Address can't be over 50 characters" data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-regex="Please enter a valid email address" data-val-regex-pattern="(?!.*\.\.)(^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s\.]+$)" data-val-required="This field is required" id="Email" maxlength="50" name="Email" value=""> , that is the CSS selector for that element.